# datetimepicker: как сделать запрет на ввод своего значения поля?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

У меня есть в системе напоминания, клиент сам устанавливает дату и время напоминания, шаг времени в поле выбора 15 минут. Использую плагин календаря, но пользователи бывает вводят 16:01 или 15:03, но надо чтобы мог ввести время с шагом в 15 минут не больше не меньше.

Поле формы

```
<input name="end_time" id="end_time" type="text" />
```

js

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#end_time').datetimepicker({
            lang:'ru',
            datepicker:false,
            format:'H:i',
            value:'<?=date('H'); ?>:00',
            step:15
        });
 });
```

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Я так и не понял, чем вам не подходят `16:01 или 15:03` ?

Comment: потому-что в напоминаниях стоит раз в 15 минут отправлять напоминания.

Comment: что за datetimepicker вы используете? добавьте в вопрос ссылку на его документацию

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, вы можете выключить редактирование `input`, сделать отдельно кнопку, которая будет менять её значение через js.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так https://stackoverflow.com/a/15482666/873481 нужно только правильно regexp подобрать (вместо /^\d{3}$/ )

```
$.validator.addMethod('minutesStep', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\d{3}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid phone number");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#end_time").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: 'minutesStep'
        }
    });
});
```

Как вариант, http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-date

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

Время

```
disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 18 }), moment({ h: 24 })]]
```

Дата

```
 $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
```

Шаги и дока тут http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping

Место в доке http://prntscr.com/9gss2h

Comment: для `00:54` отдельный элемент предлагаете добавлять? :)